# FileNotFoundException on saving file to external storage

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gallery, filenotfoundexception

I have a button that downloads an image to the phone gallery using Picasso library.. the image is downloaded but I can't save it to the gallery..

I'm trying to save the image to the DCIM folder using the following code :

```
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    FileOutputStream out = null;
                    try {

                        String name = Environment
                                .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)
                                + "/"
                                + pageTitle
                                + "-img"
                                + System.currentTimeMillis() + "." + imgExt;

                        Log.d("Bitmap", "Name: " + name);

                        File f = new File(name);
                        out = new FileOutputStream(f);
                        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);


                        Intent mediaScanIntent = new
                        Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
                        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
                        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
                        SinglePageActivity.this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                        try {
                            if (out != null) {
                                out.close();
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Bitmap", "Null image");
                }
```

But I get the following exception :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /storage/sdcard/DCIM/offer11-img1438046842226.jpg: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)
>   Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

on this line :

```
out = new FileOutputStream(f);
```

Also is there a more efficient way to save the image to the gallery directly ?

Thanks

Comment: it's basically because it's not the app's folder owner. . you need to create your own folder

Comment: Isn't it possible to save a photo to the photos directory of the device ?

Comment: Like I said it is possible.. however make your own folder with mkdir.. it is just like other apps.. Ex: Photo Studio.. it creates a new folder Photo Studio then the gallery automatically reads it as a new album

Answer (score 0):

check if you have declared the permission in

```
    AndroidManifest.xml

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>,
```

if not,then try to add;

Comment: check if the path /storage/sdcard/DCIM/ is right,if "sdcard" is wrong,system can not creat automatically.you can check path with adb shell

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
public class ImageDownload implements Target {

    public static final String TAG = "tag";

    private String name;

    public ImageDownload(String fileName) {

        name = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("/"));

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(final Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        Log.e("ImageDownlaod", "inside Download ");

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                        .getPath() + "/" + FACTOR_APP + "/" + name);
                try {
                    file.createNewFile();
                    FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, ostream);
                    ostream.close();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



}
```

and you can use this class as

```
public void downLoadImagesWithPicasso() {

                Picasso.with(this).load(thumbnailPath)
                        .into(new ImageDownload(thumbnailPath));


    }
```